# Mongoose Embeded Document Not Saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For anyone who plays Guild Wars 2, this schema may look familiar.  I am attempting to download all items through their API, and am having trouble getting the embedded 'details' property to marshal and/or persist.  This is my first stab at using mongoose, so I'm hoping there is a glaringly obvious problem here:

Here is my Schema definition:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    icon: String,
    description: String,
    type: String,
    rarity: String,
    level: Number,
    vendor_value: Number,
    default_skin: Number,
    flags: [String],
    game_types: [String],
    restrictions: [String],
    details: {                // This is the problem property
        type: String,
        weight_class: String,
        defense: Number,
        infusion_slots: {
            flags: [String],
            item_id: Number
        },
        infix_upgrade: {
            attributes: [{
                attribute: String,
                modifier: Number
            }],
            buff: {
                skill_id: String,
                description: String
            }
        },
        suffix_item_id: Number,
        size: Number,
        no_sell_or_sort: Boolean,
        description: String,
        duration_ms: Number,
        unlock_type: String,
        color_id: Number,
        recipe_id: Number,
        charges: Number,
        flags: [String],
        infusion_upgrade_flags: [String],
        suffix: String,
        bonuses: [String],
        damage_type: String,
        min_power: Number,
        max_power: Number
    }
});
```

I have attempted to save the incoming objects through both insert and findOneAndUpdate (upsert).

```
var gwItem = // grab from API.
Item.remove({_id: gwItem.id}).exec();
// At this point, details looks like an object property.
gwItem['_id'] = gwItem.id;
var item = new Item(gwItem);
// At this point, calling item.toObject() shows no 'details' property set...
item.save().exec();  // 'details' not saved here
// Do below in replacement of item.save();
gwItem['$setOnInsert'] = {_id: gwItem.id};
// This saves 'details' property with a value of '[object Object]'...
Item.findOneAndUpdate({_id: gwItem.id}, gwItem, {upsert:true}, function(){});
```

Example of what the API sends and is populated into 'gwItem' in above code: https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/68743

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of how Mongoose defines schemas. Since you used the keyword `type` as a pathname for `details` it defines `details` as a `String` field and the rest of your paths are options for `details`. Simply change `type: String` to `type: {type: String}` and you should be all set. More info [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2104).